# getting an error "ns_error_unknown_protocol

Tags: php, javascript, protocols

im getting an error "ns_error_unknown_protocol" when i run this code in firefox.whats the problem with my code?i run this in google chrome,but it runs without any problem.it doesnt display any error messages?please help me out.

my javascript is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
var wrong="nnnn.htm";  
    var name = prompt("Please type in the password",''); 
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'password.php',
    data: {
    name: name
        },
    success: function(data) 
    {
        if (data.success == "good") 
             {


                 window.location.href =data.address;

             }    
        else 
             {
                 alert(data);
                location.href=wrong
             }
    },
    error: function(data) 
    {

        location.href=wrong;
    },
        });
        });
    </script>
```

my php page is

```
<?php
$password="123";
$prompt_password=$_POST['name'];
$success="good";
if($prompt_password==$password)
{
$output =  array('success'=>'good',
          'address'=>'itms-services://?action=download-   manifest&url=http://feathersoft.net/projects/tests/Corelogic/Alert/AlertApp.plist');
echo json_encode($output,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
else
{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

Comment: Firefox is showing that error because it does not now how to handle `itms-services://` protocol.

Comment: @vedarthk I think it should be answer. :)

Comment: any way to solve this?

Comment: but when i write the url as window.location.href="that url".its working

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is showing that error because it does not now how to handle `itms-services://` protocol.

Goto `about:config` in Firefox and search for `network.protocol-handler` if you can see any setting for `network.protocol-handler.external.itms-services` then only Firefox can handle your request.

Change `self.location.href = data.address` to `self.location = data.address` as `href` is used for HTTP.

Comment: OP says it works when typed directly in, so the browser does know how to handle it.

Comment: Ok, the issue is with `href` as pointed out by @epascarello `href` is for HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `ns_error_unknown_protocol` is basically saying is the browser does not know how to handle your custom protocol `itms-services://`.

I thinking it has to do with the href setting.

Try changing it to

```
self.location = data.address;
```

Comment: What i do now.but when i write the url as window.location.href="that url".its working..

Comment: I gave you a stab in the dark answer.