# Error in firefox console while trying to reflect a querys result(cleint side) in a div (client side) using ajax object

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, firefox

The error's screenshot shared below

[image]
I have written a javascript function which is triggered when I select a certain option from a dropdown menu. A query is executed on the server side based on this selection and the response is to be displayed inside a div on the client side , but I am getting a strange error in my console in firefox. Would really appreciate if someone can help me out on what I am comitting wrong.
here is the javascript that i have written

```
function changeLocation()
        {
            var x= document.getElementById("state");
            var val = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;// value selected by user in state is assigned to variable var

            var xhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            { // Mozilla, Safari, ...  
                 xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
            } 
            else if (window.ActiveXObject)
            { // IE 8 and older  
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
            }  
            xhttp.open("GET","localhost/location.php?t=" + val,true);//variable being sent is t
            xhttp.send(null);

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()//error checking required
            {
                 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    //document.getElementById("location").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    var ajaxdisp = document.getElementById("location")
                    ajaxdisp.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;//need to look through full manual for it
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("needs Debugging");
                }
             }
        }
```

here 'state' is the id of the dropdown and 'location' is the id of the div where i need to reflect the change

the php code is

```
<?php
            include "logconnect.php";
            $t = $_REQUEST["t"];
            $result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT location FROM office where state = '".$t."'");
            $disp = "<select>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $disp .= "<option>";
                $disp .= $row['location'];
                $disp .= "</option>";
            }
            $disp .= "</select>";
            echo $disp;?>
```

The question is different from <[getting an error "ns_error_unknown_protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409270/getting-an-error-ns-error-unknown-protocol)> as here the error is related to some function , that might be due to firefox's internal settings, not recognizing ajax , these are my best guesses but I need help to identify the correct one.

Comment: try this? `xhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/location.php?t=" + val,true);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting an error "ns\_error\_unknown\_protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409270/getting-an-error-ns-error-unknown-protocol)

Comment: Also, from [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Errors), *NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL(0x804B0012) means The URI scheme corresponds to an unknown protocol handler.*

Comment: @Zak that didn't help , still getting the same error,

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I know it corresponds to an unknown protocol handler , but what specifically it is over here that is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble people , I have finally found the error, it was actually that in some places of my script I had written xmlhttp instead of xhttp. Thanks a lot for your help :) and really sorry for the trouble .